# Producing 'installers' on Linux

Tags: linux, software-installation, packaging

can you help me with

- best practices or things that i should keep in mind while we produce an 'installer' for my software (Java based)?
- what are the steps or phases in which this should be done?

I researched and found out that doing this via package managers is a good way of doing it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Apologies for asking a bit 'open ended' question. I would be careful

Answer (score 3):

Windows-style self-extracting installer packages are arguably a bad practice:

- the self-extractor can become a vector for malware: nobody questions why an installer must be run as administrator.
- if an obscure installer generator is used, the contents of the package can be inaccessible by regular extraction and anti-malware tools, making for another way to hide malware.

Although existing package managers may not be perfect, using their package formats has several security advantages:

- the package formats are well known and cryptographically signable, so tampering can be easily detected
- if necessary, the tools to extract such a package for inspection without executing a single byte of code from the package itself are readily available
- the package formats support executing pre/post-installation/removal scripts, which can perform any custom configuration steps you might need
- at least the `.deb` packaging format includes an uniform method of specifying package configuration for fully automated non-interactive installations (known as "preseeding" in Debian/Ubuntu world).

No matter what you do, if your software is intended for use on servers, you should ensure that your software can be easily installed non-interactively. If you don't do this, the administrators using tools like Ansible, Salt or docker-compose will hate your software.

In order to package managers to be automatically install any dependent libraries or other packages for you, you must document the dependencies in package metadata. You should test your packages by installing them to a VM with a "minimal" installation of the appropriate distribution, and verifying that the dependencies will automatically pull in everything your software package needs.

You should also make sure any dependencies will allow for security updates: specifying package dependencies as "needs version X or greater of package Y" are better than "absolutely needs version 1.2.3.4 of package Y".

Major distributions can have documentation on recommended software packaging practices. For example, Debian has [a policy manual for Java software.](https://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/java-policy/) Although you can deviate from it if you don't plan to have your software included in the distribution, you should still read it to understand how a `.dpkg`-packaged Java software is expected to be handled.

Comment: thanks telcoM  for this. This helps!